# Bug? is remove() supposed to remove from associated lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Set 2nd list equal to 1st list

```py
first_lzt = ['room', 'floor', 'name']
second_lzt = first_lzt
```

`remove()` element from 2nd list.

```py
second_lzt.remove('room')
```

The element surprisingly also gets removed from the 1st list. Why?

```py
>>> first_lzt

['floor', 'name']
```

Is that supposed to happen? How can I make `second_lzt` independent without appending items into it?

Python 3.7.6

---

EDIT: expected object behavior.

```py
str1 = "apple"
str2 = str1
str2 = str2 + "_pie"

>>> str1
"apple"
```

```
int1 = 3
int2 = int1
int2 += 4

>>> int1
3
```

Comment: Copy the list instead. You're currently only assigning the reference, *the exact same reference*. Any mutation to one reference will reflect changes across all variables storing the same reference. [Copying operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Assignment does not make a copy of the list. You only have a single list object with 2 names pointing to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python modifying wrong list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337106/python-modifying-wrong-list)

Comment: These are the *same list*, not two "associated" lists. This is always the semantics of assignment. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Is this behavior specific to lists? I feel like I haven't experienced this before.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax no, absolutely not. This is the semantics of the *assignment statement* always, it has nothing to do with type. Read the Ned Badtchelder link

Comment: sooo that link makes it seem like it is specific to lists.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax no it doesn't. What part about "Fact: Assignment never copies data." seems specific to lists?

Comment: read my OP edit

Comment: strings are immutable - you can never mutate them in the first place

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax if you `print(int1)` it's still `3` as well. **Please just read the link**

Comment: @Chase **completely irrelevant** in this case. You can get the same exact behavior with lists: `list1 = [1,2,3]; list2 = list1; list1 + [4]; print(list1); print(list2)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga OP posted an example with strings

Comment: @Chase **the type of the items in the list are completely irrelevant**. The fact that `str` objects are immutable doesn't matter to the semantics of assignment, which never changes due to type.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax you are not understanding. **Assignment never copies**. You can *always* re-assign a name to another object. Again, you get *the exact same behavior with lists*: `list1 = [3]; list2 = list1; list2 + [3]; print(list1)`

Comment: thanks for the explanations. at the end of the day, regardless of the inner workings of assignment, as an end user, this behavior feels inconsistent with the rest of the language. otherwise, i wouldn't be making this post.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax It is entirely consistent across the whole language. It is also the same exact semantics of most similar languages, e.g. Java, JS, Ruby etc etc Do you come from a C background? C and C++ work differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a list independent, use `.copy`. For example:

```py
first_lzt = ['room', 'floor', 'name']
second_lzt = first_lzt.copy()
```

Now, if you do `second_lzt.remove("room")` it will remove room from **only** the second list.

Answer (score 0):

yes, its not creating a second list under the hood, like @Chase says you are referencing a variable to the list. Nothing more.

#Copy List Using Slicing Syntax

```
first_lzt = ['room', 'floor', 'name']
second_lzt = first_lzt[:]
```

[watch your code in action](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=first_lzt%20%3D%20%5B%27room%27,%20%27floor%27,%20%27name%27%5D%0Asecond_lzt%20%3D%20first_lzt%0Asecond_lzt.remove%28%27room%27%29%0Aprint%28first_lzt%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)